# How to add negative margin in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, position, margin

How can I add negative margin in IE7?
My code is:

```
.product-tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -17px;
}
```

In all browsers it works like I wan't except in IE7, I tried to replace margin with `top:-40px; left:-17px;` but then block moves up and leaves empty space at the bottom.
Also I tried changing `position: relative` to `position: absolute`, but then `.product-tabs` parent div height is 0.

Answer (score 0):

used to this

```
.product-tabs {
    position: relative;

top:-40px;
left:-17px;bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: And how can I get rid of empty space at the bottom?

Comment: replace position relative to absolute if no than show me your completed code with html and css

Comment: Did you even read my question? You are saying me to do things which I already tried. As I said if I change position relative to absolute then parent div height is 0, so this isn`t good solution for my problem.